# JRuby on Rails assets:precompile does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, asset-pipeline, assets, precompile

I have an rails application in JRuby, when I run `rake assets:precomile` it only creates a file `/public/assets/manifest.yml` with this content:

```
--- {}
...
```

None of the asstes get precompiled, but I dont get any error when I try to trace this:

```
tbraun@tbraun-DEBIAN:~/Dokumente/Entwicklung/RubyOnRails/Passbildkartei$ rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/tbraun/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7.2/bin/jruby /home/tbraun/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:nondigest
```

But I have some images, javascripts and stylesheets in my assets directories, I don't know what I can do to fix this.

My JRuby version is:

```
jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-05-01 26e08ba) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_26) [linux-amd64-java]
```

And this are the gems I am using:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem "haml", "~> 3.1.4"
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.3"
gem "devise", "~> 2.1.2"
gem "devise_ldap_authenticatable", "~> 0.6.1"

gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'

gem 'jruby-openssl'
gem 'json'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'therubyrhino'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.3.4"

  gem "warbler", "~> 1.3.5"
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can avoid this by adding

> config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

To your application.rb

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem by myself. It was the `devise` gem that caused the `assets:precomile` to fail because it needs access to the databse. But my production db is only accessible through VPN. So you just need to make sure to have access to the db when using devise when precomiling the asstes.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. the `devise` gem again. using heroku so I had no valid production db info in my config file. Copied my development config to the production section in config/database.yml just to make it work. There's probably an easier way round...